# Map URL to sub-folder using Route annotation in ASP.NET 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Let's assume I have this file structure:

```
-Controllers
--api
---1.0
----UserController.cs
```

And I wan't to be able to access user controller via following URL: `/api/1.0/users`

so it's fine to write something like:

```
[Route("api/1.0/[controller]")]
public class UserController : Controller
```

But now I want to make base controller for all my controllers and want to put generic route annotation which will identify api version based on subfolder. So if controller in `[1.0]` sub-folder it should be accessed via `/api/1.0/controller` but if it's in `[2.0]` sub-folder, than link should be `/api/2.0/controller`.

So I need to modify route annotation somehow to support this. Something like

```
[Route("api/[some_kind_of_subfolder]/[controller]")]
```

How to do this in Asp.net5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no way to do that with `Route` attribute. There is probably some chances to make it using `areas` or using new MVC6 concept - `Application Model Conventions (IApplicationModelConvention interface)` Detailed example [there:](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3107)

And this is [good post](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/03/strongly-typed-routing-asp-net-mvc-6-iapplicationmodelconvention/) describing how to make strongly typed routing